# Telegram bot C# - Отправка emoji 2022

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста как отправить эмодзи через Telegram bot? Пытался отправлять unicode смайлов всех видов `U+1F601` , `\xF0\x9F\x98\x81`,`\U0001F601`, но во всех случаях печатает сам код в тексте или пишет ошибку: Не удается преобразовать из "string" в "Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ParseMode".

Comment: А что мешает просто взять и отправить сразу емодзи? Допустим: `client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "");`, уверен, что телеграмм это позволяет.

Comment: Большое спасибо) Сразу не додумался

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("\U0001F601");` работает  (https://sharplab.io), быть может вы как-то неверно строку формируете.